# Unexpected collapse of dimension when calling np.tile()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, tile

I am creating a multi-dimension *numpy* matrix like this:

```
a = np.array([255, 0])                            
mins_and_maxes = np.tile(a, [9, 2, 43])
```

I'm expecting `mins_and_maxes` to be a 4-D array with a shape of *(9, 2, 43, 2)*.  However, `mins_and_maxes` has a shape of *(9, 2, 86)*.  The *[255, 0]* arrays are sort of being 'dissolved'.  (I can't think of a better word.  "Exploded"?)

How do I get a matrix of size *(9, 2, 43)* where every element is a copy of the array of length *2*, *[255, 0]*?

Comment: *"How do I get a matrix of size (9, 2, 43) where every element is a copy of the array of length 2, [255, 0]?"* That would be an array with shape (9, 2, 43, 2).

Comment: you told it expand size 2  by 43 times.  As with broadcasting new leading dimensions are automatic.  trailing are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
a = np.array([255, 0])

mins_and_maxes = np.tile(a, [9, 2, 43, 1])

mins_and_maxes.shape
#(9, 2, 43, 2)
```

mins_and_maxes

```
#array([[[[255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         ...,
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0]],
       [[[255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         ...,
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0]],

        [[255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         ...,
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0]]],


       [[[255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         ...,
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0]],

        [[255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         ...,
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0],
         [255,   0]]]])
```